# How to popup a notification panel in Xul without taking focus from the current window?

Tags: popup, focus, notifications, xul

I would like to popup a notification window in front of any window, but without take focus, like a messenger notifications..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Floating_Panels

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Panels